# What (x, y, z) with longest Euclidean distance in this distance function, when distance is 3?

Tags: geometry

The distance function from (x, y, z) to (0, 0, 0) is:

$5x^2+2y^2+6z^2-6xy-2xz+2yz=(distance)^2$

When the statistical distance is 3,  which (x, y, z) has longest Euclidean distance to the origin?

Please give me the process or just solve it by using a calculator is also fine.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried these points

Comment: ( $(3√5)/5$,0,0),($(-3√5)/5$,0,0),(0,$(3√2)/2$,0),(0,$(-3√2)/2$,0),(0,0,$√6/2$),(0,0,$(-√6)/2$)

Comment: Are the points I tried satisfied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculus approach: The equation
$$\bigl(g(x,y,z):=\bigr)\qquad5x^2+2y^2+6z^2-6xy-2xz+2yz=9$$
defines an ellipsoid centered at the origin. Maximize the function $f(x,y,z):=x^2+y^2+z^2$ under this constraint.